# Call to LotusSession.GetDatabase works in VB but not in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, lotus-domino

I have some old VB code to send mails using Lotus Notes that works, I have re-written it into C#, but it behaves differently:

VB:

```
    NotesSession = CreateObject("Notes.Notessession")
    NotesDb = NotesSession.GetDatabase("", "")
```

C#:

```
    _notesSession = new NotesSession();
    _notesSession.Initialize(passwordString);
    _notesDatabase = _notesSession.GetDatabase( "", "");
```

First of in C# I need to Initialize the NotesSession with a password, and secondly it will not accept empty string parameters at runtime. Exception is thrown: "A database name must be provided".

In both VB and C# I refer to the same COM : Lotus Domino Objects

I need to be able to call the GetDatabase without specifying the server and database file.

Thanks in advance.

Solution (Thanks guys):

```
     dynamic _notesSession = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesSession"));
     _notesDatabase = _notesSession.GetDatabase("", "");
```

This way you have no intellisense but all properties and methods can be found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_4_LOTUSSCRIPT_NOTES_CLASSES_REFERENCE.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new instance of the `NoteSession` type in C# using the `new` keyword, it will use the COM-interop dll that was referenced by the project at build-time.  That is not exactly the same thing as calling `CreateObject`, which requires no interop dll.  The closer equivalent in C# would be:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.Notessession");
_notesSession = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Or, if you really need to do the *exact* same thing, you could always add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` library and then call the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject` method from C#.

As Richard pointed out in the comments below, the likely reason why you are seeing a difference in behavior is because you are creating two different types of objects.  Presumably, when you call `new NotesSession` in C#, it is using the `NotesSession` class from the `Lotus` namespace, rather than the one in the `Notes` namespace.

Comment: It's important to understand that there are two distinct sets of very similar "back-end classes" for Notes.  There are OLE classes rooted at 'Notes.NotesSession", and there are COM classes rooted at "Lotus.NotesSession".  The old VB code was using the OLE classes, not the COM classes.  And as I said, the COM and OLE classes are similar --  but not identical.

Comment: Ah!  Excellent clarification.  Thanks @RichardSchwartz.  That makes much more sense.  I am not familiar with Notes, so I didn't realize that.  I will update my answer.